# SQL Server Full Text Search Results differs from Like statement

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I tried these two methods on Advantureworks and got different results.

1. `select * from Person.[Address] where AddressLine1 like '%99%'`
2. `select * from Person.[Address] where contains(Address.AddressLine1,'"*99*"')`

Any Idea?

Comment: As far as the theory suggests. The results should be identical.

Answer (score 1):

Full text search and LIKE are two completely different things:

- `LIKE` works on strings of characters and matches exactly.
- `CONTAINS` works on words and is somewhat fuzzy (how the strings are broken up into word parts depends on the language and can be customized even further if needed).